# Implementing 2 ATS specifications on plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9

My app includes both Chartboost's and Facebook's SDKs. Following iOS 9 ATS requirements I have tried to make the plist file as described on those two suppliers websites.

I want to combine those two into one but I'm not sure how.
Can someone help me with that ?

Chartboost instructions :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>chartboost.com</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true />
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

Facebook instructions:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: You can only have one NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary - combine the two

Comment: Can you please explain it better ?

Answer (score 1):

You an only have a single `NSAppTransportSecurityDictionary` in your plist file.
You need to combine all the exceptions into one instance of `NSExceptionDomains` under a single `NSAppTransportSecurity` -

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>chartboost.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```